# Inheritance and initialization in swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, initializer

I have been trying to create two different classes: for the superclass I create my properties and init() function with the appropriate parameters. However, when I create my subclass with its own properties and init() function I get into trouble.

What I'm trying to achieve here is that at some point in my app, the user will enter a bunch of fields and when he/she is ready and clicks the 'ready' button, the content of the fields will be used as arguments for my init() function of the subclass. The superclass's init() has less parameters than the init() of the subclass.

I've been reading about designated and convenience initializer but I'll a bit confused. Maybe I don't really need them, I'm not sure.

What i'm trying to avoid is having to change the value of any of the properties of the subclass manually after the call to init().

Any help is much appreciated.

/// NEW CODE:

class Habit {

```
enum HabitType {
    case health
    case wealth
    case social
    case career
    case noType
}

var habitID: Int
var title: String
var type: HabitType
var duration: Int
var toAccomplish = [String]()
var currentFeelings = [String]()
var howToFix = [String]()

init?(habitID: Int, title: String, type: String, duration: Int, toAccomplish: [String]?, currentFeelings: [String]?, howToFix: [String]?) {

    self.habitID = habitID
    self.title = title
    switch type {
    case "health":
        self.type = HabitType.health
    case "wealth":
        self.type = HabitType.wealth
    case "social":
        self.type = HabitType.social
    case "career":
        self.type = HabitType.career
    default:
        self.type = HabitType.noType
    }
    self.duration = duration

    if let accomplish = toAccomplish {
        self.toAccomplish = accomplish
    }
    if let feelings = currentFeelings {
        self.currentFeelings = feelings
    }
    if let fix = howToFix {
        self.howToFix = fix
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

class MiniHabit: Habit 
{

```
var trigger: String
var action: String

init(habitID: Int, title: String, type: String, duration: Int, toAccomplish: [String]?, currentFeelings: [String]?, howToFix: [String]?, trigger: String, action: String) {

    ////init() Error: A non-failable initializer cannot chain to failable initializer 'init(habitID:title:type:duration:toAccomplish:currentFeelings:howToFix:)' written with 'init?' 
    super.init(habitID: habitID, title: title, type: type, duration: duration, toAccomplish: toAccomplish, currentFeelings: currentFeelings, howToFix: howToFix)

    self.trigger = trigger
    self.action = action

}
```

}

Comment: Could you post the code for your classes?

Comment: Can you post some sample code?  It’s not clear what the problem you’re hitting is – it’s fine for a superclass to have fewer parameters for its `init` than the subclass, so long as a) the subclass initializes all _its_ properties, then b) it calls the superclass’s `init`

Comment: Well I think my code is a mess right now. I overcomplicated stuff but what I'm trying to achieve is to assign values to all properties of my subclass using its init(). I'm trying to avoid having to assign values to some properties by for example saying: object.property = textfield.value. Hopefully I'm being more clear.

Comment: If you feel any of the answers solved your question would you consider marking one as correct? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are to things wrong with your code:

1. You don't need the `required` keyword in the initializer. As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID231):

> Write the `required` modifier before the definition of a class initializer to indicate that every subclass of the class must implement that initializer

2. The properties you assign in the superclass' initializer should not be assigned in the subclass

This code works in a Playground (Xcode 6.3):

```
public class Habit {
    var habitID: Int
    var title: String
    var type: String
    var duration: Int
    var toAccomplish = [String]()
    var currentFeelings = [String]()
    var howToFix = [String]()

    public init(habitID: Int, title: String, type: String, duration: Int, toAccomplish: [String]?, currentFeelings: [String]?, howToFix: [String]?) {

        self.habitID = habitID
        self.title = title
        self.type = type
        self.duration = duration

        if toAccomplish != nil {
            self.toAccomplish = toAccomplish!
        }
        if currentFeelings != nil {
            self.currentFeelings = currentFeelings!
        }
        if howToFix != nil {
            self.howToFix = howToFix!
        }
    }
}

public class MiniHabit: Habit {
    var trigger: String = ""
    var action: String = ""

    public init(habitID: Int, title: String, type: String, duration: Int, toAccomplish: [String]?, currentFeelings: [String]?, howToFix: [String]?, trigger: String, action: String) {
        super.init(habitID: habitID, title: title, type: type, duration: duration, toAccomplish: toAccomplish, currentFeelings: currentFeelings, howToFix: howToFix)

        self.trigger = trigger
        self.action = action
    }
}

var h = MiniHabit(habitID: 0, title: "", type: "", duration: 1, toAccomplish: nil, currentFeelings: nil, howToFix: nil, trigger: "", action: "")
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a few changes to your code, this is how it looks now:

```
// 1.
class Habit {
    var habitID: Int
    var title: String
    var type: String
    var duration: Int
    var toAccomplish = [String]()
    var currentFeelings = [String]()
    var howToFix = [String]()

    init(habitID: Int, title: String, type: String, duration: Int, toAccomplish: [String]?, currentFeelings: [String]?, howToFix: [String]?) {

        self.habitID = habitID
        self.title = title
        self.type = type
        self.duration = duration

        // 2.
        if let acomplish = toAccomplish {
            self.toAccomplish = acomplish
        }

        if let feelings = currentFeelings {
            self.currentFeelings = feelings
        }

        if let fix = howToFix {
            self.howToFix = fix
        }
    }

    class MiniHabit: Habit {
        // 3.
        var trigger: String
        var action : String

        init(habitID: Int, title: String, type: String, duration: Int, toAccomplish: [String]?, currentFeelings: [String]?, howToFix: [String]?, trigger: String, action: String) {
            // 4.
            self.trigger = trigger
            self.action = action

            super.init(habitID: habitID, title: title, type: type, duration: duration, toAccomplish: toAccomplish, currentFeelings: currentFeelings, howToFix: howToFix)
        }
    }
}
```

**1.** You **probably** don't need to declare your class as public. From the documentation:

> Public access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, and also in a source file from another module that imports the defining module. You typically use public access when specifying the public interface to a framework.

By default your classes will be have `internal` access, which should be fine if you're not intending to create a framework from these classes.

For more information see *Access Control* in *The Swift Programming Language*, link here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

**2.** Using optional binding, using `if let`, is preferred to checking if an optional is nil and then force unwrapping it. See *The Swift Programming Language* for more information on optional binding.

**3.** `trigger` and `action` don't have to be given initial values of empty strings as long as you set them **before** you call super init. Swift enforces that all properties defined in your current class must be initialised before `super.init` is called. Because you're setting them before your `super.init` call, could also use `let` instead of `var` for `trigger` and `action` if you wanted them to be immutable.

**4.** You're now only initialising the variables that `MiniHabit` defines, all the other variables are left to be setup by the designated initialiser on `Habitat`.

Also, I notice you have a `type` variable in `Habit`. If `type` should only be a select few values I would recommend using an `enum`, for example:

```
class Habit {
    enum HabitType {
        // Give these more appropriate names.
        case HabitType1
        case HabitType2
        case HabitType3
    }

    var type: HabitType

    // Other variables...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and code change. I will check out the documents you mentioned.

Comment: I updated my code for the Habit class. I was trying to add it to the post but it complains the message is too long.  How can I post it so you can see it? I'm not getting any error but wanted someone more experienced to check it out for me.

Comment: If that's the case, perhaps you could remove your old code from the post to give you some more space? But make it clear this is your new code after looking at the answers.

Comment: I've added a new answer so this answer didn't get too long.

Answer (score 1):

**New answer in response to updated code**

It's looking better than last time, but there are still a few changes you could make:

**Firstly,** you don't need to use a switch statement to check which enum type `type` should be. You can use pass the enum type as the argument to the initialiser. For example, say this was your `Habit` class:

```
class Habit {
    enum HabitType {
        case Health
        case Wealth
        case Social
        case Career
    }

    let type: HabitType

    // Don't use a String here, use the HabitType enum.
    init(type: HabitType) {
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

You could then create an instance of Habit like so:

```
let aHabit = Habit(type: .Health)
```

See *enumeration* in *The Swift Programming Language* for more information.

**Secondly,** in regard to your `HabitType` enum, I see you've got a case `NoType`. This would be a perfect place to use optionals instead of using `NoType`. For example, you could declare the variable `type` to be an optional, then when it equals `nil` you know there was no type. For example, this would be your `HabitType` enum:

```
enum HabitType {
    case Health
    case Wealth
    case Social
    case Career
}

// And this is how could could define type to be optional.
let type: HabitType?
```

**Thirdly,** the error you're getting in `MiniHabit`'s initialiser is because you've declared `Habit`'s initialiser to be failable (denoted by the `?` after `init`). This is not necessary in this situation and instead your initialiser could look like this:

```
// Not failable anymore. 
init(habitID: Int, title: String, type: String, duration: Int, toAccomplish: [String]?, currentFeelings: [String]?, howToFix: [String]?) {

    // Setup other variables

    if let accomplish = toAccomplish {
        self.toAccomplish = accomplish
    }
    if let feelings = currentFeelings {
        self.currentFeelings = feelings
    }
    if let fix = howToFix {
        self.howToFix = fix
    } 

    // No need to return nil if the user didn't supply a value for howToFix.
}
```

For more information on failable initialiser see here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17

Hope that helps! Let me know if there's anything else that needs clarifying.

Comment: I made the changes regarding point one. For point two, I decided to make 'type' an optional property because the compiler was throwing an error within my switch code: about a missing 'default' case. Now, I realize I don't need 'type?'. For the third point, I made the changes and it's working now. I actually included the return nil line because of the failable init(), although, it was in the wrong place anyways. ABakerSmith, thanks a mill for your help!! :)

Comment: In case you encounter the error again - you'll get the 'missing a default case' error if you haven't included every possibility in your switch statement, in the case of enums this means you've got to have a case in your switch for every case in your enum. Awesome though, glad you got everything working!